# Using glGetFloatv to retrieve the modelview matrix in pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, ray-picking

I'm doing 3d visualization in python using pyglet, and need to retrieve the modelview and projection matrices to do some picking. I define my window using:

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import *

win = Window(fullscreen=True, visible=True, vsync=True)
```

I then define all of my window events:

```
@win.event
def on_draw():
    # All of the drawing happens here

@win.event
def on_mouse_release(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == mouse.LEFT:

    # This is where I'm having problems
    a = GLfloat()
    mvm = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, a)
    print a.value
```

When I click, it will print...

```
1.0
Segmentation fault
```

and crash. Calling glGetFloatv with GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX is supposed to return 16 values, and I'm not exactly sure how to handle that. I tried defining a = GLfloat*16 but I get the following error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_float instance instead of _ctypes.PyCArrayType
```

How can I retrieve these matrices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass 16 element float array. To do that use following code:

```
  a = (GLfloat * 16)()
  mvm = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, a)
  print list(a)
```

Of course, you can access individual elements of "a" by using a[0] syntax.

Comment: can you share the interpretation of those 16 elements in a? which element represents what?

Comment: column-major, per my understanding.  ie first 4 are first column of matrix.